# Writing a bash script not getting the expected output

Tags: bash, centos7, scripting

This is the bash script I am writing. You can see the expected output. But I am getting something else. Where could I be making a mistake?

```
#!/bin/bash
    #Demostrate how read actually works
    echo What cars do you like?

    read car1 car2 car3

    echo Your first car was: $car1
    echo Your second car was: $car2
    echo Your third car was: $car3
```

Expected output

```
./cars.sh
What cars do you like?
Jaguar Maserati Bentley Lotus
Your first car was: Jaguar
Your second car was: Maserati
Your third car was: Bentley Lotus
```

Actual Output

```
[root@localhost ~]# ./cars.sh
What cars do you like?
Jaguar
Your first car was: Jaguar
Your second car was:
Your third car was:
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: This looks like what I'd expect from the defined behavior of the `read` command. If you input too many words, the extra collects in the last variable (thus `car3` is "Bentley Lotus" in your first example). If you don't input enough words, it leaves the later variables empty (thus, `car2` and `car3` are blank in your second example).

Comment: Btw for scripting questions the sister site [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) might be the better place.

Answer (score 0):

In second case you are not providing all the variable values. There is nothing wrong in your script.

```
# bash -x cars.sh
# What cars do you like?
# Jaguar Maserati Bentley Lotus
```

Try to debug with -x if you still face an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is working now. I had failed to give all the inputs when the first line popped up. Its working now.

[root@localhost ~]# ./cars.sh
What cars do you like?
Jaguar Ferrari Maseratti Suzuki
Your first car was: Jaguar
Your second car was: Ferrari
Your third car was: Maseratti Suzuki

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable number of input arguments you could use an array variable by using `read -a variable_name` like in this example.

Example: cars.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

read -a cars -p "What cars do you like? "

echo "You have entered ${#cars[@]} cars"

declare -i count=0
for car in "${cars[@]}"; do
        echo "Car number $(( ++count )) was: $car"
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./cars.sh
What cars do you like? bmw audi mercedes
You have entered 3 cars
Car number 1 was: bmw
Car number 2 was: audi
Car number 3 was: mercedes
```